# Can I use Bill of Materials to order components online?

Tags: eaglecad, bom

I am working on a project in which I am designing a circuit board with a lot of components (resistors, capacitors, ICs etc) using AutoCAD Eagle. I am done with the schematic part and currently I am ordering components online. I have found this process very time consuming and tedious. I have to order each individual components with the correct values, which requires a lot of searching.

Recently, I came across a feature in Eagle - Bill of Materials, which generates a list of all the components and their values and details. Is it possible to upload Bill Of Materials on electronic vendor websites to speed up ordering process?

Comment: If your BOM has a sufficient detail, such as proper vendor specific (or even generic) part numbers - you can definitely automate this process and come to agreement with the vendor.

Comment: You will still have to select individual parts since the same part can be supplied by different manufacturers, come in multiple types of reels, packages, temperatures, grades etc. But the BOM manager will facilitate that if you already have the base part number in the BOM you uploaded.

Comment: Yes, this works in some cases- generics may be  a problem and inevitably over time parts, or entire series of parts, become unavailable or better options arise. Even if your BOM is rigidly locked to one or more exact options for each part exceptions will arise. For example, if you had standardized on manufacturer XX 0603 1% resistor and your preferred distie or the manufacturer themselves drops it then you have a lot of work to do to update every instance of every value in your product line.

Comment: I like using Octopart's BOM tool. It provides you with the cheapest options for parts within your preferred list of suppliers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most vendors have import BOM functions, and as long as you have a Manufacturer's part number in there, and the quantity, the import process is pretty much painless.
That is why it pays to spend some time creating a good part library.

I have used Digikey a few times, and it works quite well. If I remember correctly I also used Farnell/Newark, and those worked fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know digi-key has a [BOM upload section](https://www.digikey.com/BOM#). I've never used it though so I'm not sure how well it works.

Comment: It's fairly decent. Mouser has one now too I believe.